# Rectangle Selection Like Tool MS Paint C#

Tags: c#, selection, paint

I have been working on creating a program similar to MS Paint. I have several of the features it has down but the one which is currently giving me trouble is the rectangular selection tool. My program currently draws everything on the panel and saves it all in an ArrayList so each shape can be redrawn in Paint().

Like MS paint I would like the user to be able to select a section of the drawing on the panel and either copy it, move it, re-size it, or even delete it. I was thinking about having the user draw a rectangle & saving the information for it. Then taking that information for the rectangle, passing them to create a new Bitmap. I would then paint a new rectangle in the background color to give the appearance that the selected area was "removed" when the selected portion is moved. It sounded okay until I realized that I couldn't use the Graphics.FromImage() on the PaintEventArgs variable passed to Paint() which made my idea useless. Not sure if that makes sense so my apologies if it's a confusing mess.

I've been searching the internet for some assistance and I haven't found much to help so either this is very easy to do, very difficult, or "rectangle selection tool" is not the proper term. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: It sounds like you have written [a "draw" program, rather than a "paint" program](http://www.pcdon.com/deDrawingAndPaintingPrograms.html). MS Paint does not remember each shape that's drawn, it just paints the shape onto the canvas, and remembers the canvas. That's why you can't move a rectangle after it's been finalized (you've clicked away). A rectangular selection tool would be a **lot** easier if you took the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you actually have the `Rectangle` and now would like to copy an area from your painted `Panel`.

This is possible, assuming you have, as you should, placed all the painting in the `Paint` event of the `Panel`.

Then you can, use `DrawToBitmap` to ask the `Panel` to draw itself onto a new `Bitmap`; from there you can `DrawImage` the `Rectangle` onto your `Panel`.

Note: For this to integrate with your list of 'Paint-Actions' you will have to either now store that `Bitmap` or store the `Rectangle` and redo the whole operation.

```
using (Graphics G = panelCanvas.CreateGraphics() )
{
    Rectangle R0 = new Rectangle(22,22,55,55); // your Rectangle!
    using (Bitmap bmp = new 
           Bitmap(panelCanvas.ClientSize.Width, panelCanvas.ClientSize.Height))
    {    panelCanvas.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panelCanvas.ClientRectangle);
         G.DrawImage(bmp, 111f, 111f, R0, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

Aside: Please do replace the `ArrayList`, which is depracated by the new `List<T>`, e.g. a `List<PaintAction>` or whatever name your class has!

If you simply want to extract a rectanglular area from the Panel Control you can use thsi function:

```
public Bitmap getAreaFrom(Control ctl, Rectangle area)
{
    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height);
    using (Graphics G = ctl.CreateGraphics())
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
        using (Graphics G2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2))
            G2.DrawImage(bmp, 0f, 0f, area, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return bmp2;
}
```

Comment: I will replace the ArrayList to List, thank you for pointing that out. VS didn't give me any warnings about it so I did not think it was deprecated. Question though for the code you added. I am just saving the BMP to ensure I have the right area, but it keeps starting at the top left of the panel, not where the user draws the selection rectangle.

Comment: ArrayList is still supported - .NET keeps things around but its use is discouraged for List<T>.  -  DrawToBitmap indeed paints the whole control. You need to use the Rectangle to extract the right area from it, like I've done in the DrawImage..

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean by extracting the right area from it like how you did it with DrawImage. I just attempted to use the code that you had provided (except I am using PaintEventArgs in my Paint() for my panel instead of CreateGraphics) and it still captured the image from the top left corner. I am saving the BMP so I can view it in Windows Photo Viewer to check if it is getting the right part of the image. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Ahhh! It saved the correct selected portion! Perfect! One step closer to implementing this select tool. Fingers crossed that I don't have to ask another question. Thank you so much for all of your help TaW, that's the 2nd question you've helped me with for this project of mine!!!!!! :)